# What tools you use to design web application in Asp.net or Asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have recently started working on web applications and i'm doing it using ASP.Net MVC. I have been checking out some open source applications.

Some of the views that i checked had alot of markup code, so i was wondering are there any other tools used to visualize and develop views, in a more visual way..

Thanks.

Comment: Any WYSIWYG editor or designer tools should be fine - but I believe one of the intents of MVC was to get people back to the basics of markup. Having some kind of generated markup seems counter to this goal...

Answer (score 1):

Never ever use WYSIWYG HTML Editors. HTML is easy to learn, hasn't much to offer since it's quite small (yet) and it's just something you need to know (in my point of view) HTML is kinda part of programmers 101. If you want to keep your HTML code small and easy to read (and reuse) just use HTML helpers ([Read about them](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs))

So there are great resources to learn HTML here are a few great resources. IMHO the best one is...
[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) - Great tutorial and even better reference

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio should be your one stop development environment.

The full version costs a few hundred but you can get your hands on the Express version for free.

The latest versions can be downloaded here:

- http://www.microsoft.com/express/

via the Web Platform Installer.

Its feature packed and virtually all of the tutorials and books you can buy / get online will cover it using Visual Studio so if you are just starting out then you should do yourself a favour and learn it this way first.

Plus its what employers will expect you to be able to use.